# Query for date interval

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table that contains a list of reservation, every reservation have an office id, a start time and and end time (along with other informations).
when i create entries the end time is caluclated as start time + a time_span (in my case 1:30)
so for a basic example i have the following data

| ID | date | start_time | end_time | office_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-21 | 2022-11-21 19:00 | 2022-11-21 20:30 | 8 |
| 2 | 2022-11-21 | 2022-11-21 19:30 | 2022-11-21 21:00 | 5 |
| 3 | 2022-11-21 | 2022-11-21 19:30 | 2022-11-21 21:00 | 4 |
| 4 | 2022-11-21 | 2022-11-21 20:30 | 2022-11-21 22:00 | 8 |
| 5 | 2022-11-21 | 2022-11-21 21:00 | 2022-11-21 22:30 | 12 |

I was trying to make a query that based on start_time (for example 20:00) will give me a list of rooms i can't book following this main rule:

- can't be booked if the start_time is between the provided one and the provided one +1:30
  OR
- can't be booked if end time is between the provided one and the provided one +1:30

so i get a query like

```
select * from Reservations where date='2022-11-21' and ((start_time>='2022-11-21 20:00' and start_time<='2022-11-21 22:30') OR (end_time>='2022-11-21 20:00' AND end_time<='2022-11-21 22:00')) order by start_time ASC;
```

it should give me all the rooms that cant be booked since they have a reservation active the window between 20:00 and 21:30, and in this case it return all results

but im not sure this is correct or this is an effective way to query, any suggestion?

Comment: Why do you store `date` and `end_time`? All you need is `start_time`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need the columns `date` and `end_time` in your table.
They can be easily obtained from `start_time`:

- `date` is `DATE(start_time)`
- `end_time` is `start_time  + INTERVAL 90 minute`

For your requirement use this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Reservations 
WHERE start_time >= ? - INTERVAL 90 minute AND start_time <= ? + INTERVAL 90 minute
ORDER BY start_time ASC;
```

or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Reservations 
WHERE start_time BETWEEN ? - INTERVAL 90 minute AND ? + INTERVAL 90 minute
ORDER BY start_time ASC;
```

Replace both `?` placeholders with the same datetime value like `'2022-11-21 20:00:00'`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-ied0mpe).

Comment: thank you! i keep also the end time, becuase it can be variable (is set from an admin)